# sql truncate and convert timezone

Tags: sql, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, utc, truncate

How can I truncate (by hour) the result of my convert_timezone query.

```
SELECT 
convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP) as Time
,date_trunc('HOUR', Time) as Truncated
FROM Date
```

Above works but I want to 'combine' it all on one line to give me a single result of truncated time.

Comment: Snowflake ---------------

Comment: Have you tried `date_trunc('HOUR', convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP))` ?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have the SQL working uncombined, just stack the command

```
WITH date(RECORD_TIMESTAMP) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-06-25 01:45:01'),
    ('2022-06-25 02:45:01')
)
SELECT 
    convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP) as Time
    ,date_trunc('HOUR', Time) as Truncated
    -- can just be stacked as
    ,date_trunc('HOUR',convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP)) as truncated_Time

FROM Date
```

gives:

| TIME | TRUNCATED | TRUNCATED_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-24 21:45:01.000 | 2022-06-24 21:00:00.000 | 2022-06-24 21:00:00.000 |
| 2022-06-24 22:45:01.000 | 2022-06-24 22:00:00.000 | 2022-06-24 22:00:00.000 |

Or just written as the stacked line:

```
WITH date(RECORD_TIMESTAMP) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-06-25 01:45:01'),
    ('2022-06-25 02:45:01')
)
SELECT 
    date_trunc('HOUR',convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP)) as truncated_Time
FROM Date
```

| TRUNCATED_TIME |
| --- |
| 2022-06-24 21:00:00.000 |
| 2022-06-24 22:00:00.000 |

Comment: This also works but I was looking for a single column output.

Comment: The third column is 100 independent. It is a single column solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Combine both columns

```
SELECT
date_trunc('HOUR', convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/New_York', RECORD_TIMESTAMP)) as TruncatedTime
FROM Date
```